# MediaWiki Internal Error : exception 'BadTitleError' with message

Tags: mediawiki

I am having an issue with media wiki , i upgraded the mediawiki but still an issue  here is the error message i am getting 
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: exception 'BadTitleError' with message 'The requested page title was invalid, empty, or an incorrectly linked inter-language or inter-wiki title.
It may contain one or more characters which cannot be used in titles.' in /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Wiki.php:197
Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Wiki.php(536): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#1 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Wiki.php(446): MediaWiki->main()
#2 /home/website/public_html/wiki/index.php(59): MediaWiki->run()
#3 {main}
```

Exception caught inside exception handler: exception 'MWException' with message 'PCRE needs to be compiled with --enable-unicode-properties in order for MediaWiki to function' in /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php:1528
Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(1160): Parser->replaceExternalLinks('')
#1 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(370): Parser->internalParse('The requested p...')
#2 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(873): Parser->parse('The requested p...', Object(Title), Object(ParserOptions), true)
#3 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Message.php(605): MessageCache->parse('The requested p...', Object(Title), true, true, Object(Language))
#4 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Message.php(434): Message->parseText('The requested p...')
#5 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Message.php(496): Message->toString()
#6 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/OutputPage.php(3528): Message->parseAsBlock()
#7 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/OutputPage.php(2062): OutputPage->addWikiMsgArray('badtitletext', NULL)
#8 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Exception.php(342): OutputPage->showErrorPage('badtitle', 'badtitletext', NULL)
#9 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Exception.php(374): ErrorPageError->report()
#10 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Exception.php(620): BadTitleError->report()
#11 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Exception.php(690): MWExceptionHandler::report(Object(BadTitleError))
#12 /home/website/public_html/wiki/includes/Wiki.php(449): MWExceptionHandler::handle(Object(BadTitleError))
#13 /home/website/public_html/wiki/index.php(59): MediaWiki->run()
#14 {main}
```

Appreciating your help thanks

Comment: Just curious, what OS platform is it?  Is it by any chance Slackware Linux?  If so, what version?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading PCRE or Perl? Have you tried compiling PCRE with that option on your own?

Comment: upgrading PCRE helped . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

skalee's solution worked for nestrocuation: Try upgrading PCRE or Perl, or compiling PCRE with that option on your own.